# draw a vertical line between 2 objects

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Is it possible to draw a vertical line between 2 text objects? I looked into this but this is not exactly what I need:

https://reactjsexample.com/draw-a-line-between-two-elements-in-react/

[image]

```
 <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>132    </Text>
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>{numberOfFriends}</Text>
        </View>
```

```
  ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 70,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    width: '100%',
  },
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
```

Edit:

I tried adding a view in between the two numbers:

```
  verticleLine:{
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#909090',
  },
```

```
  <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
          <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
          <Text style={styles.numbers}>{numberOfFriends}</Text>
        </View>
```

but it's not in the center
[image]

Answer (score 18):

One way to do this is to create a view then give it a `height of 100%`, `width of 1px` and `background-colour`. Then proceed to place this View in-between the two elements.

[image]

```
 <View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
    <Text style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
    <View style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
    <Text style={styles.numbers}>2</Text>
 </View>

ridesFriends: {
    paddingTop: 70,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  verticleLine: {
    height: '100%',
    width: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#909090',
  }
```

Comment: The line isn't exactly in center. Is there any way to fix the line in the center?

Comment: @Jnl what is that extra spaces after 132?

Comment: I already removed that but the line is still not in center. Probably because 132 has more digits and 2 has 1 only. @Mohammad

Comment: please share your numbers styles

Comment: I just tried it now. it's properly aligned with those styles @Jnl

Comment: I just update the answer. The code  is the same as what you have

Comment: But my line's not in the center :/ It comes in center if I change 132 to just 3 or something. But otherwise, the line is more towards the right.

Comment: Maybe you should stop metro bundler and run the app again

Answer (score 4):

You can simply give the object on the left (`styles.numbers`) a `border-right: 1px solid gray;`. You can do that for all items in a row, and you can make a condition to remove the border for the "last child".

Comment: I tried this but nothing appears ```num1: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: "bold",
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#909090',
  }``` Note that I am using stylesheets in react native

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={styles.ridesFriends}>
   <div className="wrapper">
      <Text className="text1" style={styles.numbers}>132</Text>
      <View className="view" style={styles.verticleLine}></View>
      <Text className="text2" style={styles.numbers}>{numberOfFriends}</Text>
   </div>       
 </View>
```

css file

```
.wrapper{
   width:100%;
}
.text1{
   width: 49%;
}
.text2{
   width: 49%;
}
.view{
  width:2%;
}
```

you can use this code,to give both the text equal space and line will be in center

Hope it helps